# logging information is being sent to more files than specified by the handler

Tags: python, python-logging

In an attempt to learn the Python module `logging` I made the small script below.
However, whenever I use the object `my_logger` it outputs to the file `my_logger.log` as specified by the file handler, but it also outputs the same text to the previously specified file in `basicConfig` `log.log`. My question is, why is it outputting to both locations instead of just the file specified by the `FileHandler`?

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, 
                    filename='log.log', 
                    filemode="w",
                    format="%(levelname)s - %(message)s")

logging.debug("debug_message")        # Lowest   |
logging.info("info_message")          #          |
logging.warning("warning_message")    #          |
logging.error("error_message")        #          |
logging.critical("critical_message")  # Highest  V

my_logger = logging.getLogger('My_Logger')
my_logger.info("Successfully created my custom logger")

handler = logging.FileHandler("my_logger.log")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)s: %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)

my_logger.addHandler(handler)
my_logger.info("Successfully created My Logger!")
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    my_logger.exception("ZeroDivisionError")
```

Comment: my_logger propagates logs to the root logger. (all loggers do). So any log sent to my_logger will appear in both files. (log.log via root, and my_logger.log)

Answer (score 0):

You have two loggers in your script. One is the root logger that is setup using basiConfig and accessed using logging keyword itself. Another logger is "My_Logger" which is a child of root logger. Both loggers are active in your script and are instructed to write to specified handlers.

That's why you are getting logs written in both files.

If you want to use a customized handler than don't use basicConfig. **Use only one logger** in the whole of your module.

Comment: are you saying that basicConfig configures the root and all loggers?

Comment: basicConfig has no effect if a handler is already assigned to the root logger. It also doesn't affect a child logger either. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig // You have two loggers (not the same thing as handlers) working independently. That's the problem.